# Deque with wraparound display not displaying all indices (Java)

Tags: java

Hello everyone I have a question!

I'm trying to implement a Dequeue with wraparound and for the most part I think I have it implemented correctly. The issue though is with displaying the contents of the Dequeue.

The part that I'm having trouble with is the else-if statement in the display method. Whenever the left side does it's wraparound I have issues.

I can't post images, you need at least 10 reputation which I didn't know about.

Input entered: 
    insertRight(10);
    insertLeft(9);
    insertRight(8);
    insertLeft(7);
    insertRight(6);
    insertLeft(5);
    insertRight(4);
    insertLeft(3);
    insertRight(7);
    insertLeft(2);

Output expected: 1 3 5 7 9 10 8 6 4 2

```
public class Dequeue
{
private int[] deArray;
private int maxSize;
private int nItems;
private int left;
private int right;

public Dequeue(int size) {
    maxSize = size;
    deArray = new int[maxSize];
    left  = (maxSize/2)+1;
    right = (maxSize/2);
    nItems = 0;
}

public boolean insertLeft(int j)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        System.out.println("The dequeue is full.");
        return(false);
    }
    if (left == 0)
        left = maxSize;
    deArray[--left] = j;

    nItems++;
    return(true);
}

public boolean insertRight(int j)
{
    //takes an integer and returns false if DQ is full, otherwise insert Right or Rear
    if(isFull())
    {
        System.out.println("The dequeue is full.");
        return(false);
    }
    if(right == maxSize - 1)
        right = -1;
    deArray[++right] = j;

    nItems++;
    return(true);
}

public int removeLeft()
{
    //if the DQ is not empty, removes and returns integer on left or front
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The dequeue is empty.");
        return(0);
    }
    int temp = deArray[left];
    if (left == maxSize - 1)
        left = 0;
    else
        left++;
    nItems--;
    return temp;

}

public int removeRight()
{
    //if the DQ is not empty, removes and returns integer on right or rear
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Dequeue is empty.");
        return (0);
    }
    int temp = deArray[right];
    right--;
    if(right<0)
        right = maxSize -1;
    nItems--;
    return temp;
}



public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return(nItems == 0);
}

public boolean isFull()
{
    return(nItems == maxSize);
}

public void display()
{
    int i;
    System.out.println("Right is equal to: " +right+" and left is equal to: " +left+ "\n");
    System.out.println("\nMaxsize is equal to: "+maxSize);

    if(isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("The dequeue is empty.");
    if(left < right)
    {
        for(i= right; i<left; i++)
        {
            if(i==maxSize)
                i = 0;
            System.out.print(deArray[i]+ " ");
        }
        for(i=left; i< right+1;i++)
        {
            if(i==maxSize)
                i = 0;
            System.out.print(deArray[i]+ " ");
        }
    }

    else if (right < left)
    {
        for(i = right; i < left; i++)
            if(i == maxSize)
                {i = 0;}
            System.out.print(deArray[i] + " ");
        for(i = left+1; i <= ((maxSize-1)); i++)
            System.out.print(deArray[i] + " ");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Oh no!");
}}
```

Comment: Add brackets around the code in your `for` loops located in the `else if (right < left)` block. i.e.) `for(i = right; i < left; i++) { code... }`

Comment: Thanks so much. Needed another pair of eyes I guess! Was able to fix up the code and solve the problem that I was having.